# What is the most efficient algorithm to find the max element of a Symetric Matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, coding-efficiency

I actually want to know how it's the best way to pick the maximum integer (the one with bigger value) of a matrix in c++ such data structure is a `map<string, map<string,int>>` both ordered in  growing lexicographic order. Actually my function returns a pair of  where the maximum element is indexed. Thank you for your time and sorry for my lack of English skills.

Comment: I'd be tempted to maintain a simultaneous `multimap<int, string>`, given the overhead you already have in building a map with strings as keys means introducing my new member would probably not be a performance concern. Then maximum element extraction is O(log N). Depends on how often you need to do it, and if you are willing to burden your code with another data member.

Comment: I actually don't want to change that data structure or add another one by the moment for some reasons (I'm really suffering with the lenguage switch sorry if I misunderstood your message)

Comment: What is the element in this case? Is it the value (`map<string,int>`) in the outer map? Is it the a `pair<string,int>` in the inner map? Is it the key (`string`) in the inner map? Is it the value (`int`) in the inner map?

Comment: It's the integer in this case, sorry for not specifying.

Comment: Ok, then if you don't want to add another layer like @Bathsheba proposed, you'll have to search through all `int`s. You won't know if you've found the max `int` until you've compared them all.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: for symmetrical matrix, just test one "side" is enough.

Comment: @Jarod42 Indeed - I need to keep the title in mind when reading the question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching whole matrix (`O(n²)`) would be:

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string,int>> matrix;

int m = matrix.begin()->second.begin()->second; // Assuming non empty
for (const auto& row : matrix) {
    for (const auto& p : row.second) {
        m = std::max(m, p.second);
    }
}
```

`map` doesn't have random access, so you cannot simply do as regular matrix

```
for (int i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
    for (int j = i; j != size; ++j) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

but you can use `lower_bound` to "possibly" speed-up:

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string,int>> matrix;

int m = matrix.begin()->second.begin()->second; // Assuming non empty
for (const auto& row : matrix) {
    for (auto it = row.second.lower_bound(row.first);
         it != row.second.end();
         ++it) {
        m = std::max(m, (*it).second);
    }
}
```

Possibly as `O(n*(log(n) + n/2))` which is still `O(n²)` with lower factor (1/2) but compares keys (which are string...)

Comment: That's a good idea. I believe you can be more efficient if you navigate the upper diagonal (from start up to `row.second.first == row.first`) since you need to navigate through half the elements anyway. Something like `for(auto it = row.second.begin(); matrix.key_comp()(it->first, row.first); it++) { m = std::max(m, it->second); }`. Using `lower_bound` would be better if the cost of the key comparison is expensive.

Comment: @JorgeBellon: It is then a trade of: you do more string comparison, but visit less map nodes.

Comment: You miss the diagonal, `!matrix.key_comp()(row.first, it->first)`.

Comment: Yes, I must admit it can get expensive if strings are long.